# Convert number to string in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, numbers

I'm trying to do some transformation with numbers in excel. First i have that table:
[image: Excel Numbers]

And as you can see, i have Random Digits, which is generated by using RANDBETWEEN. Now i want the Column Type, to be automatically Generated. So for example if Random Digits is:

- From 1 - 35 = Good
- 36 - 80 = Fair
- 81 - 100 = Poor

I was already trying with IF function, but with if function i'm able to generate only 2 values and not 3.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excel formula you are looking for is

```
=IF(B1>100,"error",IF(B1>=81,"Poor",IF(B1>=36,"Fair",IF(B1>=1,"Good","error"))))
```

This will display the word "error" if you range is >100 or <1. Other answers have failed to address the cases where the number is >100 or <1, as the question specifically bounds the set of responses to be between 1 and 100.

The formula works as a nested if statement. In pseudo code the formula is equivalent to:

```
if(B1>100)
   then "Error"
Else if (B1>=81)
  then "Poor"
Else if (B1>=36)
  then "Fair"
Else if (B1>=1)
  then "Good"
else
  "Error"
```

Comment: No problems, do you mind up voting my response if it answered your question?

Answer (score 3):

`INDEX` and `MATCH` are a good way to avoid nesting lots of `IF` statements (generally to be avoided!):

```
=INDEX({"Good","Fair","Poor"},MATCH(B2,{0,36,81},1))
```

If you really wanted to use an `IF` statement, it would look like this:

```
=IF(B2<36,"Good",IF(B2<81,"Fair","Poor"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one `IF` inside another `IF` like this:

```
=if('From 1 - 35';'thing to do if is true';if('36 - 80';'thing to do if is true';'thing to do when is 81 - 100'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Nest the If so where you get the true value just output what you need but if its false then just write another if statement...